# "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/sample.csv'" の対処方法を教えて下さい

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-lab

環境は Windows10, Jupyter Lab です。
下記のコードをコピーペーストして実行した所、エラーが出ました。

私が解決のため行ったことは、

- エラー文を対訳して意味を検索で調べました。（意味は、そのようなファイルまたはディレクトリはありません）
- エラー文を検索する。（Google）

検索等を参考に気づいたことは、Jupyter Labのデスクトップに”CSVファイル”自体が無いのに気づきました。
その後、色々と考えましたが…元のスキルがないので考えようがありません。
ご教授、宜しくお願い致します。

```
from time import sleep                                      
from selenium import webdriver                                      
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options                                       
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                       
import textwrap                                     
import csv                                      
                                        
#windows(chromedriver.exeのパスを設定)                                        
chrome_path = r'C:\chromedriver.exe'#driverを入力                                      
                                        
#mac                                        
#chrome_path = 'C:/Users/デスクトップ/python/selenium_test/chromedriver'                                      
                                        
#　amazonのレビュー情報をseleniumで取得する_引数：amazonの商品URL                                       
def get_amazon_page_info(url):                                      
    text = ""                               #　初期化                                       
    options = Options()                     #　オプションを用意                                      
    options.add_argument('--incognito')     #　シークレットモードの設定を付与                                       
    #　chromedriverのパスとパラメータを設定                                      
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path,options=options)                                      
    driver.get(url)                         #　chromeブラウザでurlを開く                                     
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)              #　指定したドライバの要素が見つかるまでの待ち時間を設定                                        
    text = driver.page_source               #　ページ情報を取得                                      
                                            
    driver.quit()                           #　chromeブラウザを閉じる                                        
                                            
    return text                             #　取得したページ情報を返す                                      
                                        
# 全ページ分をリストにする                                      
def get_all_reviews(url):                                       
    review_list = []                        #　初期化                                       
    i = 1                                   #　ループ番号の初期化                                     
    while True:                                     
        print(i,'page_search')              #　処理状況を表示                                       
        i += 1                              #　ループ番号を更新                                      
        text = get_amazon_page_info(url)    #　amazonの商品ページ情報(HTML)を取得する                                     
        amazon_bs = BeautifulSoup(text, features='lxml')    #　HTML情報を解析する                                       
        reviews = amazon_bs.select('.review-text')          #　ページ内の全レビューのテキストを取得                                        
                                                
        for review in reviews:                              #　取得したレビュー数分だけ処理を繰り返す                                       
            review_list.append(review)                      #　レビュー情報をreview_listに格納                                     
                                                    
        next_page = amazon_bs.select('li.a-last a')         # 「次へ」ボタンの遷移先取得                                     
                                                
        # 次のページが存在する場合                                      
        if next_page != []:                                         
            # 次のページのURLを生成                                          
            next_url = 'https://www.amazon.co.jp/' + next_page[0].attrs['href']                                         
            url = next_url  # 次のページのURLをセットする                                       
                                                    
            sleep(1)        # 最低でも1秒は間隔をあける(サーバへ負担がかからないようにする)                                      
        else:               # 次のページが存在しない場合は処理を終了                                       
            break                                       
                                        
    return review_list                                      
                                        
#インポート時は実行されないように記載                                     
if __name__ == '__main__':                                      
                                            
    #　Amzon商品ページ                                        
    url = 'https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%89%8B%E6%8C%87%E6%B6%88%E6%AF%92%E5%89%A4%E3%80%91%E3%83%8F%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5EX-%E3%81%A4%E3%81%91%E3%81%8B%E3%81%88%E7%94%A8-800ml-%E8%8A%B1%E7%8E%8B%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%83%95%E3%82%A7%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B7%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BA-%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E5%8C%BB%E8%96%AC%E9%83%A8%E5%A4%96%E5%93%81/dp/B005RUI15O/'                                        
                                            
    # URLをレビューページのものに書き換える                                      
    review_url = url.replace('dp', 'product-reviews')                                       
    # レビュー情報の取得                                     
    review_list = get_all_reviews(review_url)                                           
                                        
    #CSVにレビュー情報の書き出し                                        
    with open('data/sample.csv','w') as f:                                      
        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')                                     
                                        
        # 全データを表示                                       
        for i in range(len(review_list)):                                       
            csvlist=[]                                      
            review_text = textwrap.fill(review_list[i].text, 80)                                        
            #データ作成                                      
            csvlist.append('No.{} : '.format(i+1))    #　便宜上「No.XX」の文字列を作成                                       
            csvlist.append(review_text.strip())         #　レビューテキストの先頭・末尾の空白文字を除去                                        
            # 出力                                            
            writer.writerow(csvlist)                                                            
        # ファイルクローズ                                      
        f.close()                                       
                                        
1 page_search                           
2 page_search                           
3 page_search                           
4 page_search                           
5 page_search                           
6 page_search                           
7 page_search                           
8 page_search                           
9 page_search                           
10 page_search                          
---------------------------------------------------------------------------                         
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)                         
<ipython-input-1-fbb91e326654> in <module>                          
67                          
     68     #CSVにレビュー情報の書き出し                            
---> 69     with open('data/sample.csv','w') as f:                          
     70         writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')                         
71                          
                            
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/sample.csv'
```

Comment: コードが入力できません。エクセルファイルで添付しましたが、できません

Comment: 画像ファイル以外は添付することができません。質問に関するソースコード等は、テキストのまま質問文に貼り付けてみてください。

Comment: 質問文の欄、…ご教授、宜しくお願い致します。に続いてコードをコピーペーストしましたが…ファイルを選択するか、ドラッグ＆ドロップするか、画像やリンクをペーストしてください…と表示されますが…

Comment: 何とかかんとか…画像にして送信しましたが…小さすぎて？

Comment: ドラッグ＆ドロップではなく、ソースコードをクリップボードにコピーして本文に貼り付けて下さい。

Comment: 「デスクトップに”CSVファイル”自体が無いのに気づきました。」とのことですが、ではそのファイルは何処にあるのでしょうか？コードが読めないのでよく分かりませんが、デスクトップをパスに指定しているのであればそこにそのファイルをコピーすれば良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 気づくのに遅れてすみません。コード、何とか見れるように修正しました。で、CSVファイルは、本コードが実行されたら生成されるはずですが…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらの記事のようにすれば、Jupyter-labの作業ディレクトリが確認出来るでしょう。
記事はJupyter-notebookのものですが、Jupyter-labでも同様と思われます。
[カレントディレクトリの確認](https://potesara-tips.com/get-current-working-directory/#toc2)

> カレントディレクトリは、標準ライブラリのosモジュールを使って確認できます。
>
> > ```
> > os.getcwd()
> > ```
>
> osモジュールをインポートして、os.getcwd()を実行します。
>
> > ```
> > import os 
> > os.getcwd()
> > ```
>
> > ```
> > 'C:\\Users\\user'
> > ```
>
> windows環境での例ですが、Cドライブの上記フォルダがカレントディレクトリと確認できました。

実際に実行した場合に後ろの`user`は貴方のユーザー名になります。

---

質問の内容については、以下のいずれかによって対処出来るでしょう。

- `data/sample.csv`という相対パスでファイルを指定する場合は、`C:/Users/username/`の下に`data`フォルダを作成し、その中に`sample.csv`ファイルを入れておけば、読み込むことが出来ます。
- フォルダを作ってファイルを移動しなくても、読み込む際に`data/sample.csv`という相対パスではなく、`C:/`から始まる絶対パスを指定すれば読み込めます。
- 以下の記事を参考にJupyter-labの作業ディレクトリ自体を変更することが出来ます。
  [Jupyter-labのデフォルトの作業ディレクトリを変更する(Windows版)](https://tkstock.site/2020/12/12/jupyter-lab%E3%81%AE%E3%83%87%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%AB%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%9C%E6%A5%AD%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%AC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%99%E3%82%8Bwindows/)

パスの区切りは`/`または`\\`が使えます。(`\`は半角の円通貨記号です。)

Comment: osモジュールを使いました。結果、CSVファイル自体が無いことが分かりました。と、言う事はコード自体に何らかの問題があると言う事と思いますので、その方向で調べてみようと思います。

Comment: 昨日は、コードを本文にコピーペースト出来ませんでしたが、今再挑戦してできました。昨日画像を添付しましたが、削除する方法が分かりません。

Comment: 下の方の`[![画像の説明をここに入力][1]][1]`から3行を削れば良いのでは？ それよりも質問のタイトル・内容と追記されたプログラムソースの最後に出ているエラーメッセージの内容が合っていないようですが、何か別のあるいは新たな問題のソースですか？ 状況的には、単にエラーメッセージに示された行桁位置に全角空白があるものと思われますが。(ちなみにプログラムソース側は修正済のようですが)

Comment: ご助言、ありがとうございます。削除と修正を行いました。